# Updating and running Git through Homebrew instead of XCode

Tags: macos, terminal, bash, homebrew, git

On my new 2014 Mac (OS X 10.9 Mavericks), I have just installed Git using Homebrew. In order to install Homebrew, I had to download and install XCode 5. So now, when I enter the command `which git`, I can see that Git is running from a different file pathway than the rest of the Homebrew installation. Git's different pathway is `/usr/bin/git`. I believe it is supposed to be in `/usr/local/bin/` instead, with the rest of Homebrew.

I found a solution to getting Git to run from the Homebrew installation (and consequently an updated version of Git). According to another Q&A on this site, the solution is to add `export PATH="/usr/local/bin:$PATH"` in `~/.bash_profile`.

Unfortunately, I don't understand where to enter that information. When I'm in Terminal, I can't change directories to something called "~/.bash_profile." How do I get there to enter the command `export PATH="/usr/local/bin:$PATH"`? I tried entering the command `/usr/bin/open ~/.bash_profile`, but Terminal tells me: `The file /Users/**MYNAME**/.bash_profile does not exist.`

Comment: Let's trouble shoot this in a chat room: http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/17163/discussion-between-ian-c-and-joker6

Comment: I would love to, thank you for offering! But I don't have enough reputation points to participate in a chat room yet. Is there another forum we can use?

Comment: You should have access to that chat now.

Answer (score 2):

This: `~/.bash_profile` is a *file*, not a *directory*. [It's a file that gets executed when you start a bash login shell](http://hacktux.com/bash/bashrc/bash_profile):

> A login shell is a bash shell that is started with - or --login.
>
> When BASH is invoked as a login shell, the following files are executed in the displayed order.
>
> 1. `/etc/profile`
> 2. `~/.bash_profile`
> 3. `~/.bash_login`
> 4. `~/.profile`

To ensure your Homebrew-installed tools appear before any other tools you can copy and paste the following in to a terminal window to update your `~/.bash_profile` file:

```
cat << 'EOF' >> ~/.bash_profile

export PATH="/usr/local/bin:$PATH"
EOF
```

This will append (`>>`) the necessary lines to `~/.bash_profile` for you in a safe manner. The append will create the file if it does not exist. The heredoc syntax used above is explained in [this nice StackOverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2500436/how-does-cat-eof-work-in-bash).

After making changes to your `.bash_profile` file you need to reload it or start a new Terminal session to see the change. To reload it in your existing session type:

```
source ~/.bash_profile
```

Comment: Thank you. My limited knowledge of Terminal: Running Git and Haml/Sass commands! So, on a new line in a new window, I copied/pasted your recommended command. This had no effect; when I checked on the location of my git repository again by typing `which git`, the pathway was in the same incorrect location. I was asked to run `sudo` commands to update XCode, so I did, and then was asked to run `brew doctor` again. I watched a new empty git repo initialize within `/usr/local/.git/`. But when I type `which git` again on a new line to verify that correct location, I just see `/usr/bin/git` again.

Comment: After changing your `.bash_profile` file you need to start a new Terminal to load the changes or run `source ~/.bash_profile` in your existing Terminal.

Comment: I have quit Terminal, re-opened it, and run your original `cat` command again. Then I entered your additional command, `source ~/.bash_profile` on a new line. I typed in `which git` again, but am still seeing the incorrect file pathway.

Comment: I've reviewed the answer from the question I referenced originally. Someone advised opening .bash_profile in a text editor with the command `/usr/bin/open ~/.bash_profile`. I entered this command and found my `export PATH="/usr/local/bin:$PATH"` command written several times (for each time I've duplicated the Terminal command). I erased the duplicate entries and kept one line of that `export PATH`(etc.) command. Does this mean that I'm now ACTUALLY using Git from Homebrew's installation in `/usr/local/.git/`--even if the `which git` command always shows me `/usr/bin/git` instead?

Comment: If `which git` is showing you `/usr/bin/git` and not `/usr/local/bin/git` then you're not using the Homebrew version of git.